# What's the best way to ask the user the same question until they find the correct path?

Tags: c#, recursion

I have a 2D array built of a map that asks the user for the coordinates x and y.  I simply want to keep asking the user for coordinates until they reach the goal.

I wonder if it would be better to use switch / case statements instead of multiple if / else if statements.  I tried writing a separate method called CoordinateInput that encapsulated the input instructions to the user and then returned if the coordinates != 'G'.  That didn't work sadly.

```
char[,] map = new char[6,6]   {{ 'W', 'W', 'W', 'W', 'W', 'W' },
                               { 'W', 'S', ' ', ' ', ' ', 'W' },
                               { 'W', 'E', 'W', ' ', 'E', 'W' },
                               { 'W', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', 'W' },
                               { 'W', ' ', 'W', ' ', 'G', 'W' },
                               { 'W', 'W', 'W', 'W', 'W', 'W' }};
for (int y = 0; y < 6; y++)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < 6; x++)
    {
        Console.Write(map[x, y] + " ");
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
Console.WriteLine("Please enter an x coordinate");
int xC = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
Console.WriteLine("Please enter a y coordinate");
int yC = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
char coordinate = map[yC,xC];
map[yC, xC] = coordinate;

if (coordinate == ' ')
{
    Console.WriteLine("You are on free block");                
}
else if (coordinate == 'W')
{
    Console.WriteLine("You are on a Wall");                
}
else if (coordinate == 'E')
{
    Console.WriteLine("You recieved an Energy Boost");                
}
else if (coordinate == 'S')
{
    Console.WriteLine("You the starting place");                
}         
else if (coordinate == 'G')
{
    Console.WriteLine("You Win!! You reached the goal!!");
}
```

Comment: `do { ... } while (!userHasWon)`

Comment: @CodeCaster this should be the answer, along with a little text like "*You want to **do** something **while the user hasn't won** (or until the user has won), therefore you can write:*"

Comment: @Rafalon it's definitely a duplicate, but I can't find one that quick, hence no full answer.

Comment: On second thought, this is a 2-questions-in-one, as OP asks how to loop until [condition] **and** what's better between `if`s/`else if`s and `switch`

Comment: Thanks for the responses, I'm experimenting with do / while loops now.  Stack Overflow is an understatement.

Answer (score 1):

This started out as a comment but it's getting way too big, so...

Please note that there are other problems in this code as well:

First, you're using `int.Parse` on the value coming from `Console.ReadLine()` - there's nothing stopping the user from entering a value like `Conley` or `Banana` which will throw a `FormatException` and blow up the game.

Second, even if the user enters a number, it can still cause an exception if the number is either or too large - that would be an `IndexOutOfBoundException`.

Third, you seem to be doing the entire thing inside a single method - violating the single responsibility principle.

Fourth, you're mixing logic with user interaction. It's not that terrible when writing a simple console application, but it's bad practice and you should avoid it to learn best practices early on.

Fifth, you're using hard coded values to draw the map. This means that if you change the map, you have to also change the loops. Use the `GetLength()` method instead.

So - first second and third can be handled by using a different method to read the coordinate from the user - something like this can get you what you need:

```
static int ReadCoordinate(string message, int maxValue)
{
    Console.WriteLine(message);
    var isValid = false;
    int value;
    do
    {
        isValid = int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out value) && value > 0 && value <= maxValue;
        if (!isValid)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please try again.");
        }
    } while (!isValid);
    return value;
}
```

Then, drawing the map in another method:

```
static void DrawMap(char[,] map)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < map.GetLength(0); x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < map.GetLength(1); y++)
        {
            Console.Write(map[x, y] + " ");
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}
```

and finally, another method for the gameplay:

```
static void GamePlay(char[,] map)
{
    bool gameOver = false;
    do
    {

        var x = ReadCoordinate("Please enter an x coordinate", map.GetLength(0) - 1);
        var y = ReadCoordinate("Please enter an y coordinate", map.GetLength(1) - 1);

        var value = map[x, y];
        var response = "";
        switch (value)
        {
            case ' ':
                response = "You are on free block";
                break;
            case 'W':
                response = "You are on a Wall";
                break;
            case 'E':
                response = "You recieved an Energy Boost";
                break;
            case 'S':
                response = "You the starting place";
                break;
            case 'G':
                response = "You Win!! You reached the goal!!";
                gameOver = true;
                break;
        }
        Console.WriteLine(response);
    } while (!gameOver);
}
```

Then, your `Main` method can simply look like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{

    char[,] map = new char[6, 6]   {{ 'W', 'W', 'W', 'W', 'W', 'W' },
                                    { 'W', 'S', ' ', ' ', ' ', 'W' },
                                    { 'W', 'E', 'W', ' ', 'E', 'W' },
                                    { 'W', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', 'W' },
                                    { 'W', ' ', 'W', ' ', 'G', 'W' },
                                    { 'W', 'W', 'W', 'W', 'W', 'W' }};

    DrawMap(map);
    GamePlay(map);
}
```

Comment: You're mentioning various problems, but apart from the fifth, not offering a solution for any, and more importantly, not answering the main question.

Comment: @CodeCaster Got interrupted in the middle. Will post a refactored code sample soon.

Comment: BTW, for easily reading int (and other types of values) from console, check out my git hub project called ExtendedConsole. [Read about it on my blog](https://zoharpeled.wordpress.com/2019/09/07/easy-way-to-customize-your-console-apps/)

Comment: Woah, this was immensely helpful.  This really helps me in creating better code in the long run.  Thank you so much!!

Comment: [Glad to help :-)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291325/how-to-show-appreciation-to-a-user-on-stackoverflow/291327#291327)